# Linux: read a variable as a file

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory called A , and I would like to know the modification date of one file/directory inside. Here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

find A | sort -d
var="$(head -2 | tail -1)"
echo "$var"
date -r $var '+%S'
```

That's basically how I want my code to be , when I do that, it only shows what's inside my directory A ( the find command), the echo doesn't work , date neither.
I have a message saying : date +%s no file or directory of this type.

I've seen some questions about using a variable as a file, but in my case I don't see anything that could cause a problem (like a use of slash). So I wanted to know if there is something wrong.

Comment: Your `head -2 | tail -1` pipeline has no input. Are you trying to print the time of the second file in alphabetical order?

Comment: Repertory: noun, plural repertories.:
a type of theatrical presentation in which a company presents several works regularly or in alternate sequence in one season.
o.O

Comment: Yeah, I also looked this one up :)

Comment: Probably 'repository' or maybe just 'directory'.

Comment: ok clue was in the error message `no file or repertory of this type`. Edited it for him.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`find A | sort -d` print sorted list of files to the standard output.

`head -2 | tail -1` makes `head` wait for data from the standard input.

With nothing coming from the standard input, I think the script should hang forever (?)

`var` is probably an empty string. So `echo` print an empty string (nothing), and a new line.

Whatever is stored in `var`, the filename is not found on the disk. This is why `date` generated this error.

Give a try to this:

```
#!/bin/bash --

 var="$(find A | sort -d | head -2 | tail -1)"
 printf "%s " "$var"
 date -r "$var" '+%s'
```

---

`find` can print last modification time of the files with `-printf` and `%T`.

Give a try to this:

```
find A -printf "%p %T@\n" | sort -d | awk 'NR==2{print ; quit}'
```

`-printf "%p %T@\n"`: prints the filename +  (space char) + `last modification time of the file as seconds since Jan. 1, 1970, 00:00 GMT, with fractional part.`

`awk 'NR==2{print ; quit}` prints only the second line.